# Draw underneath the icons

Tags: delphi

I am looking for a method to draw a bmp / text underneath the windows desktop icons using delphi.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Substitute the background image?

Comment: Not change the wallpaper i am looking into a dinamic way witch will alow me to change it very fast

Comment: This sounds like the same question that you asked yesterday. What exactly do you want to draw?

Comment: Just a bitmap? You don't want to show a video like you asked yesterday?

Comment: First i want to try with a bitmap and maybe i will extend with videos if it's not very complicated.

Comment: you can use Active Desktop (`IActiveDesktop`) to put web/HTML pages on your desktop (your can also embed video in it). you can test it via `Customize Desktop` in the display properties (xp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Desktop canvas. The trick is that, first, onFormCreate, you capture the desktop canvas handle in a delphi TCanvas.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDesktopCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
  FDesktopCanvas.Handle := GetWindowDC(0);
end;
```

And later destroy it onFormDestroy.

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDesktopCanvas.Free;
end;
```

In your code, you just use FDesktopCanvas as a regular canvas, every time you need to draw...

```
FDesktopCanvas.pen.Color := clWhite;
FDesktopCanvas.pen.Width := 5;
FDesktopCanvas.moveto(Screen.Width, 2);
FDesktopCanvas.lineto(2, 2);
```

...

```
var  aBitmap: TBitmap;
....
aBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
try
  aBitmap.LoadFromFile('logo100px.bmp');
  FDesktopCanvas.draw(Screen.Width-200, 100, aBitmap);
finally
  aBitmap.Free;
end;
```

...

```
FDesktopCanvas.Font.Name := 'Segoe';
FDesktopCanvas.Font.Size   := 36;
FDesktopCanvas.Font.Color  := clWhite;
FDesktopCanvas.Brush.Style := bsclear;
FDesktopCanvas.textout(Screen.Width-200, Screen.Height-100,FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss',now));
```

Comment: that will draw on the desktop icons too

Comment: ooops you're right. One possible way could be to turn the icons invisible before drawing. But that certainly would produce an annoying flicker effect. Let me think if I find another solution.